How to Export the Content of a Specific Tab in Google Docs as a Blob or PDF using Google Apps Script?
I’m working on a project where I need to extract the content of a specific tab within a Google Docs document and export it as a Blob or a PDF file using Google Apps Script.
Currently, I can retrieve the full content of the document using the Google Docs API, but I need to isolate the content of just one tab. The content is divided by tabs, and I’m looking for a way to specifically target the content of one tab (not the entire document) and export it in a format like Blob or PDF.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Accessing the document using the Google Docs API and reading the full content.
Attempting to manipulate the content to isolate a specific tab, but I’m unsure how to extract only the content from that tab, especially in a structured format like PDF or Blob.

Can anyone provide guidance or sample code on how to:

Identify and isolate the content of a specific tab.
Export this tab’s content as a Blob or PDF file.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Yes it was a duplicate of the mentioned one. And the other question has answers as well :)
